# How to check if SCNAction has completed in Swift 3

Tags: swift, scenekit

Here i have a group of animations that act on a `SCNSphere` called `testNode`

```
//run this during the duration of the two animations below
earthNode.runAction(SCNAction.rotateBy(x: 0, y: 5, z: 5, duration: 4))
//run this action right away
earthNode.runAction(SCNAction.moveBy(x: 0, y: 0, z: -5, duration: 2))
//RUN THIS ACTION AFTER ACTION ABOVE IS COMPLETED
earthNode.runAction(SCNAction.moveBy(x: 0, y: 0, z: 5, duration: 2))
```

I am trying to stop the last two animations from happening at the same time. How can i check if the second animation is completed to then run the last animation listed. I would also appreciate an explanation to checking if a group of animations running at the same time are finished.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a sequence like with SKActions:

```
/* Actions */
let moveUp = SKAction.moveBy(x: 0, y: 100, duration: 1.0)
let zoom = SKAction.scale(to: 2.0, duration: 0.25)
let sequence = SKAction.sequence([moveUp, zoom])

let node = SKNode()
node.run(sequence)
```

There's **SCNAction.group()** and **SCNAction.sequence()** for this:

```
class func group([SCNAction])
```

Creates an action that runs a collection of actions in parallel.

```
class func sequence([SCNAction])
```

Creates an action that runs a collection of actions sequentially (this is what you need I guess).

```
/* Action with sequence of actions */
let move = SCNAction.sequence([moveUp, moveDown, moveLeft, moveRight]) // will be executed one by one
let rotate = SCNAction.rotateBy(x: 0, y: .pi, z: 0, duration: 2)

/* Group actions */
let group = SCNAction.group([rotate, move])

node.runAction(group, completionHandler:nil)
```